# How to notify group of users whenever Records is inserted/edited in salesforce?

Tags: apex, chatter

We want to notify group of users whenever a record is created/edited . Can anyone please let me know what is the best way to achieve this?
We thought we can achieve this easily by chatter groups but we came to know that one user can follow only 500 records.

Comment: Workflow with email.

Comment: I think implementation depends on how you identify which users are notified for which records.  Is it just one constant group that is notified every time?  Do you want users to be able to self identify as a recipient, or do you want admins to set the recipients?  While it's straightforward to send a notification to a static group using workflows, if it's more dynamic there are a lot of potential approaches depending on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create workflow rules for the desired objects. When you create the rule, you have the option to run it every time a record is inserted. You can also set other conditions for the rule to run.

[image: Creating the workflow rule]

Then you should add an action for the rule by clicking the "Edit" button.

[image: Click the edit button to add a new action]

And finally you can add your action. Which should be Email Alert, in your case. In the next page you will be able to select specific users to send the message, or groups of users.

[image: Select the group, role, or whatever you need here]